# Does DataNucleus / NeoDatis support fetch groups?

Tags: java, database, jdo, datanucleus

If I'm reading this correctly it's saying that **NeoDatis does not support JDO fetch groups**. Am I correct in that interpretation?

---

*On the DataNucleus page for NeoDatis:*

> The following are known limitations of
>   the current implementation
>
> NeoDatis doesn't have the concept of an "unloaded" field and so
>   when you request an object from the
>   datastore it comes with its graph of
>   objects. Consequently there is no
>   "lazy loading" and the consequent
>   impact that can have on memory
>   utilisation.

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/neodatis/support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the DataNucleus website cannot be clearer on what is supported in which datastore
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/datastore_features.html

Comment: aha, yes, there it is. I hadn't seen this page, I had only thought to look at the data store-specific page for this kind of information. Thanks for pointing this out.